# WebUSB - "Unable to claim interface" error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, usb, webusb

I'm tryng to use an POS printer through WebUSB API with the code below but it fails at `.claimInterface()` with an error of `DOMException: Unable to claim interface`. All tests are done on Chrome 80.0.3987.116 on Linux. How can I debug this?

(update) I found [this demo](https://github.com/drffej/webusb.printer/blob/master/printer.html) but it results same error.

```
async function start () {
    const device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({
        filters: [{
            vendorId: 0x04b8,
            productId: 0x0202
        }]
    });
    await device.open();
    await device.selectConfiguration(device.configurations[0].configurationValue);
    await device.claimInterface(device.configurations[0].interfaces[0].interfaceNumber);
}
```

Of cource I'm running it on localhost server (which is ["secure context"](https://www.w3.org/TR/secure-contexts/)) and calling `start()` function with user gesture.

I also confirmed that no other processes are using the device.

```
% lsof /dev/bus/usb/001/011
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
chrome  4156 ikr7  393u   CHR 189,10      0t0 331233 /dev/bus/usb/001/011
```

And below is the output of `lsusb -vs 001:011`.

```
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 04b8:0202 Seiko Epson Corp. Receipt Printer M129C/TM-T70
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x04b8 Seiko Epson Corp.
  idProduct          0x0202 Receipt Printer M129C/TM-T70
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 EPSON
  iProduct                2 EPSON UB-U01III
  iSerial                 3 20110125210031250M02C
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0020
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was `usblp` driver that was automatically loaded by Linux kernel. Adding it to the blacklist solved the problem. Here's my `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklistusblp.conf` file.

```
blacklist usblp
```

Note that blacklisting `usblp` disables all USB printers that uses `usblp` driver but fortunately most people including me use CUPS as a printer driver.

(update) Figured out it would be better to write an udev rule that automatically detaches the kernel's default drivers rather than blacklisting. Here's my `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-escpos.rules`.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0202", MODE="0664", GROUP="wheel", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n $id:1.0 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usblp/unbind && echo -n $id:1.0 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbfs/unbind'"
```

This rule also unloads `usbfs` which occasionally loaded by the kernel when `usblp` is detached.